# How can I subtract a color from an UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, preprocessor, subtraction

I'm using CoreML to predict my model. However, the result is quite weird than I do in Python. Then I found that CoreML doesn't normalize the input image if I don't want to do lots of complicated setting before using .mlmodel.

So I do the preprocessing in Swift. I get the average color of image but I can't find a way to subtract from image.

How can I subtract a color from an UIImage?

Such as: `img = img - mean(img)`

Comment: You might want to look into the **CoreImage** framework. It provides a lot of off-the-rack filters, including blending with all the standard modes ("screen", "overlay", and I assume "subtract" must be there too). If the built-in filters aren't enough, you can roll your own by combining existing filters or straight out writing your own kernel. `UIImage`, in contrast, is a very high-level, basic API.

Comment: I've tried to write my kernel, but as a beginner I'm not sure how can I set the color of the image of a pixel, should I convert the image to byte array?

Comment: I don't know; I have never really looked into kernels in detail or have written any for that matter. But I thought they work on a per-pixel basis, kind of like a _shader_? (I might be wrong). I any case, I'm almost sure that what you want to accomplish can be done using the built-in filters.